# Is this the correct way to overlay div elements?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to overlay the comments `div` element over the main `div` element however am unsure of the following;

1. Is this correct?
2. Is there a better way to achieve it?

An example of the code can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/fTbP5/

**CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type=" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-us" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <meta name="copyright" content="&copy; 2012" />

    <title>sample layout</title>

    <base href="" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="" />

    <style type="text/css" media="all">

        * {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #eeeeee;
            font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
            color: #ffffff;
        }

        #content {
            width: 700px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-left: auto;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-color: #ffffff;
            border-style: solid;
            overflow: auto;
            padding-top: 40px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
        }

        #header {
            font-size: 1em;
            color: #FFC700;
            margin-left: 100px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .main {
            float: left;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            background-color: #00ACED;
            margin-left: 100px;
            padding: 20px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .comments {
            width: 320px;
            background-color: black;
            position: absolute;
            top: 305px;
            left: 0px;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .shoutbox {
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: orange;
            margin-left: 50px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .border {
            border-width: 15px;
            border-color: #ffffff;
            border-style: solid;    
        }


    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">


    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="header"><h1>Title</h1></div>
            <div class="main border">
                Hi {Name}, <br /> Your details are.
                <div class="comments">comments</div>
            </div>
            <div class="shoutbox border">shoutbox1</div>
            <div class="shoutbox border">shoutbox2</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, what exactly are you unsure of?

Comment: @DZittersteyn - As mentioned that although I am achieving the result I am after, I am unsure whether it is a hack on my part to get it to appear that way or there is a correct way of achieving the same result if my attempt at it is considered a hack?

Comment: Quick suggestion: use  `bottom: 0;` instead of `top: 305px;`. Then if you want to change the height of the outer div later, you don't have to reposition the comments box.

Comment: One more thing: your question would be much more readable if you only posted the *relevant* code (basically, the HTML for `div.main.border`, and the CSS for `.main`, `.border` and `.comments`.

Comment: Ooh, maybe add P-tags around the Hi {Name}.. Etc. bit?

Comment: @bfavaretto - I did not know that I could actually do that. That's a great thing to know. Awesome.

Comment: @bfavaretto - Point taken. The only reason I included the entire code was so that if people wanted to copy and paste the code to test on their own devices

Comment: @bfavaretto - Is my attempt to achieve the overlay correct though i.e.  it isn't just a hack that I managed to get away with to work and there is a better approach to it.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey, In this case, you can also provide a live, working code on http://jsbin.com/ or http://jsfiddle.net. (Sorry if I'm being picky here, I'm just trying to clarify Stack Overflow's best practices).

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly okay. Your comments div is nested into main and absolutely positioned inside it. No hack here. But many (most?) CSS positioning tricks do look like hacks though. Sometimes they look ugly, but are the only way to achieve some effect.

Comment: @bfavaretto - Not sure if you are a CSS guru but if you are, would you do something similar. The reason I ask is I don't want to be picking up and implementing bad habits in code. By the way this isn't homework, I am just picking up the basics of CSS and XHTML.

Comment: I don't consider myself a guru, but I do use that kind of positioning strategy *frequently*. What I also try to do is to avoid floats as much as I can, as they are easy to get out of control. When possible, I use alternate solutions with absolute or relative positioning, or `display: inline-block`.

Comment: @bfavaretto - Not sure whether you can provide your comments as an answer but if you do, I'll award the acceptance of the answer to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments above, I think your solution is perfectly okay. Your comments div is nested into main, and absolutely positioned inside it. I see no hack here.

But that is not the only way to achieve that, and I'll show you another one, which is a little more flexible. Namely, it makes your main box and your comment box allow variable height contents (while with your current solution, text would overflow outside their containers).

It's based on two things:

1. Another div with class `main-contents` to wrap the contents. It's a child of `.main`
2. The use of `min-height` on `.main`, `.main-contents` and `.comments`, to guarantee your original dimensions, but expand down if needed.

**HTML**

```
<div class="main border">
    <div class="main-contents">
        Hi {Name}, <br /> Your details are.
    </div>
    <div class="comments">comments</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main {
    width: 340px;
    min-height: 340px;
    background-color: #00ACED;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.main-contents {
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 262px;
}

.comments {
    background-color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 18px;
}

.border {
    border-width: 15px;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    border-style: solid;    
}​
```

To demonstrate that, I have set up a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/Fn6qS/) showing both your original content, and another block with taller content below it.